# Auto Login WKwebview

Tags: php, xcode, cookies, swift4, wkwebview

I have a swift 4 project and I would like to have a Auto Login feature, which means that when the users was logged in once and he restarts the app he gets automatically logged in how can I do this here is my Code: I use a WKwebview to do this i used Swift 4 if this helps. I also tryed to add a process pool as you can see in the code but it doesnt work.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class viewHome: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

weak var navigationDelegate: WKNavigationDelegate?

static let processPool = WKProcessPool()

@IBOutlet var webViewHome: WKWebView!

 override func loadView() {
       let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
       webConfiguration.processPool = viewHome.processPool
       webViewHome = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
       webViewHome.uiDelegate = self
       webViewHome.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
       //webViewHome.configuration.preferences.javaEnabled = true

       view = webViewHome

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.linopura.de/jtl.php")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webViewHome.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
    //webViewHome.configuration.preferences.javaEnabled = true
    webViewHome.load(request)
}






@IBAction func GoBackHome(_ sender: Any) {


    if webViewHome.canGoBack {

        webViewHome.goBack()

    }

}





@IBAction func GoForwardHome(_ sender: Any) {


    if webViewHome.canGoForward {

        webViewHome.goForward()

    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking to keep user login persistent

In your MainVC where user lands after login try this

```
func saveLoggedState() {
            let def = UserDefaults.standard
            def.set(true, forKey: "isLoggedin")
            def.synchronize()
    }
```

call saveLoggedState() in viewdidload

In your Appdelegate

```
let def = UserDefaults.standard
        let isLoggedin = def.bool(forKey: "isLoggedin")

        if isLoggedin {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabbarController")
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        }
```